# Client subscription increases memory usage on server side

Tags: node.js, opc-ua, node-opcua

- (X) support request

**Current behavior**
Limit or monitor client queueSize,  sampling interval, publishingInterval and maxNotificationsPerPublish from server side.
Client subscription increases memory use too much (above 1GB of RAM) in server (node-opcua).

**Expected behavior**
Detect from server side client subscription parameters and limit them or monitor them.

Server:
nodejs v 12.20.1-alpine in Docker 20.10.5
Ubuntu 18.04.4 lts
4 CPUs
8GB RAM

- (X)  my request is related to node-opcua acting as a OPCUA SERVER
- (X) I have installed node-opcua as a package ( using npm install )

  - (X) Linux   : version : Ubuntu 18.04.4 lts
- **node-opcua version:**  :
  2.33.0
- **Node:**
  `node --version` = 12.20.1
- **Typscript:**
  `tsc --version` =

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of an issue you've posted on the node-opcua issue tracker. https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/issues/955